# $\sum a_n$ divergent with $\lim(n a_n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Can we find an example of a divergent series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
where the sequence $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of real numbers, but such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n a_n)=0$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n \log n}$$ for $n \geq 3$. By Cauchy Condensation, this grows like $$\frac{2^k}{2^k \cdot k \log 2} \sim \frac{1}{k}$$